# Missing ';' before 'template<'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, templates, header-files

I'm getting a strange error when I'm compiling my program:

`Error  1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before ''template<''`

I'm doing everything pretty standard; nothing out of the ordinary:

```
#ifndef HEAP_H
#define HEAP_H
//**************************************************************************
template<typename TYPE>
class Heap
{
    private:
        TYPE* heapData;
        int currSize;
        int capacity;
        void _siftUp(int);
        void _siftDown(int);
        int _leftChildOf(int) const;
        int _parentOf(int) const;

    public:
        Heap(int c = 100);
        ~Heap();
        bool viewMax(TYPE&) const;
        int getCapacity() const;
        int getCurrSize() const;
        bool insert(const TYPE&);
        bool remove(TYPE&);
};
```

Not quite sure what's wrong. I tried closing and reopening my program - no luck. Using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: Are you including another header that doesn't have a semicolon after a class definition?

Comment: My money is on the code you're not showing us :)

Comment: Are you `#include`ing any headers?

Comment: @jrok nothing above the #ndef - not including any headers, nothing special.

Comment: @JesseGood - I have my #endif - but it doens't have a semicolon - I forget if it needs one though.

Comment: Other header with class definition that doesn't end with } perhaps?

Comment: @rhalbersma, It's ok if they're not global and don't have a capital or underscore after. Certain codebases require data members to satrt with one.

Comment: Show us some code which actually reproduces the problem. The code you posted doesn't compile because of the missing `#endif`. If I add that, it compiles just fine. It's kind of hard to troubleshoot issues that are described as "I have some code which exhibit a problem. Here's some code which *doesn't* exhibit the problem. Now what is my problem?"

Comment: This is a header file, right?  It could be the header file that is #included just prior to this one that is missing a `;`.

Comment: My Heap is included in other classes, but I don't think that matters, right?

Comment: The real question is: How to find the source where the `;` is missing and the usual answer is: Check the preprocessor output.

Comment: @jalf - not sure how to replicate it - it doesn't seem to do this in any of my other classes - which is why it's so strange.

Comment: Look at Drew's answer below, then (a) open the **source** file (.cpp, cc) file exhibiting the problem, (b) goto the `#include` section, (c) find the header listed immediately *before*  the header listed above, (d) open said header, and finally (e) goto the bottom and see if he (Drew) is right in his answer.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: you could try the obvious solution: take the code you **have** which causes the problem. And gradually, delete chunks of code from it, until you get down to a small, simple example which exhibits the problem. Also read http://whathaveyoutried.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That error can be a little misleading.

It's not necessarily important that a `;` occur **before** `template<`.

The `;` was actually expected **after** whatever *did* occur before `template<`.

This example shows how this could happen.

File `header.h`

```
class MyClass
{

}
```

File `heap.h`

```
#ifndef HEAP_H
#define HEAP_H
//**************************************************************************
template<typename TYPE>
class Heap
{
};

#endif
```

File `main.cpp`

```
#include "header.h"
#include "heap.h"

int main()
{
}
```

**Edit:**

The reason this compiler error led you to the wrong file is that *before* compilation, the preprocessor will process `main.cpp` into this single stream of characters.

```
class MyClass
{

}

//**************************************************************************
template<typename TYPE>
class Heap
{
};

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit, It's the most logical one, really.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit Maybe a guess, but I'd bet some cheddar it is correct.

Comment: Ha! Wild guess that works. Strange it says the problem is in 1 file when really it's another. In my Main - I declared a header file before my Heap that was missing a semicolon.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee The reason for that is the preprocessor removes the concept of *individual files* before the compiler gets to produce that error.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee: You could legally have `#include "foo.h"` followed by `#include "bar.h"`, where `foo.h` has a declaration with a missing semicolon, and `bar.h` has the semicolon. It would be horribly poor style, but perfectly legal. If `bar.h` *doesn't* provide the required semicolon, the compiler has no way of knowing that until it sees what's in `bar.h` -- so that's where it reports the error. (The proper fix is to add the semicolon to `foo.h`, but the compiler doesn't care where you put the semicolon; it's just reporting where it first figured out that it was missing.)

Comment: @KeithThompson *Good* compilers will report the error in the header where the `;` is missing (`header.h` in the above example), e.g. recent versions of GCC and Clang do that.

Comment: @DanielFrey: How recent? gcc 4.7.2 doesn't, at least with the example I tried.

Comment: @KeithThompson For me 4.7.2 (to be exact: `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.2-2ubuntu1) 4.7.2`) is good enough.

Comment: @KeithThompson I see, of course it won't work in *all* cases. It works for missing `;` after a class definition as this is a common problem and hence GCC/Clang can detect *these* cases. But they can't do wonders. Not yet. ;)