# Why does "using namespace System;" result in a missing type specifier?

Tags: namespaces, c++-cli, system

I was working on a class "Board" that seemed to do everything just fine. Somehow, after about an hour of work on other classes, Board showed some pretty odd behavior in terms of errors.

```
//headerfile
#pragma once

using namespace System;

#include "stdafx.h"

ref class Board
{

public:
   Board();
   ~Board();
   void printToConsole();

private:
    array<int^, 2>^ boardData;
};
```

The Errors i got for this code are:

```
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'using'  e:\users\felix\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\Board.h Line:4 Column:1    ConsoleApplication1 

Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   e:\users\felix\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\Board.h Line:4 Column:1    ConsoleApplication1
```

Line 4 is "using namespace System;" Can anybody explain what I did wrong?
This seems particularly odd because I've got another class "Pattern" that looks pretty much like this but does not output any error.

**EDIT:**

So as some of you already told me, the semicolon may be missing in the headerfile i included before this one. Also there was a similar question, thanks for posting that one ;)
so this now is my stdafx.h (without comments):

```
#pragma once
#include "Board.h"
#include "Pattern.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
```

as far as I know this pragma was there when I created this Console Application with VS, so there doesn't seem to be anything ever executed before including "Board.h".
I overlooked all my other files and I have never included Board anywhere else than here...

**EDIT 2:**

as I try to track down the error further, i noticed a missing "using namespace System;" in another class which I inserted. This resulted in a pretty interesting behavior, as the error now gets located in stdafx.h when I use namespace System in there aswell. If I don't the error will be located in the first file that gets included in stdafx.h
When I change the order of files, the first one always is the one that seems to be missing a ; before "using"... strange thing.

Comment: Sounds like you might have an error in a file that is included prior to this one in another file.

Comment: Almost certainly you are missing a semi-colon from the header file you included *before this one*.

Comment: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092520/missing-before-template#comment22975696_16092520), I, too, bet it's the same issue.

Comment: `stdafx.h` should be the first line besides any comments. Also, this isn't C++. And AFAICR, `stdafx.h` should only be included in cpps.

Comment: @chris oh thanks for mentioning that. now that you say it, it makes sense, but until now i just included stdafx.h in nearly every file because it kinda works with #pragma once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heureka!
The mistake lay in stdafx.cpp wich I find strange because I can't remember to have ever edited it but, oh well.

```
stdafx//.cpp : source file that includes just the standard includes
// ConsoleApplication1.pch will be the pre-compiled header
// stdafx.obj will contain the pre-compiled type information

#include "stdafx.h"
```

as you can clearly see, "stdafx" got interpreted as an incomplete statement where a type-specifier and a ';' were missing, thus the two errors.
As everyone in the comments already told me correctly, the error then was kinda send downwards by inclusion to the other classes. and was shown where the first real line of code (not directives) occurred.

the chain worked as follows:

```
stdafx.cpp -> stdafx.h -> the first headerfile included in stdafx.h -> "using namespace System;"
```

Anyway thanks for the help, I wouldn't have figured this out anyway else :)