# Namespace with 2 forms

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, namespaces, c++-cli

I have namespace "Client" with form MainWindow and form MyForm

MainWindow creates MyForm.

MainWindow.h

```
#pragma once

namespace Client {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    public ref class MainWindow : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MainWindow(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
....
....
....
}
```

in MyForm.h i write this:

```
#pragma once

namespace Client {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    private:
        MainWindow ^f;  //this is my problem
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
......
......
......
}
```

After compile, i have this error in line `MainWindow ^f;`:

```
1>c:\users\user\desktop\testlist\client\MyForm.h(17): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '^'
1>c:\users\user\desktop\testlist\client\MyForm.h(17): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>  MyForm.cpp
```

If i write this  `Client::MainWindow ^f;`:

```
1>c:\users\user\desktop\testlist\client\MyForm.h(17): error C2039: 'MainWindow' : is not a member of 'Client'
1>c:\users\user\desktop\testlist\client\MyForm.h(17): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '^'
1>c:\users\user\desktop\testlist\client\MyForm.h(17): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>  MainWindow.cpp
```

1 errror - The form is a member of Client, why?

if add `#include "MainWindow.h"`, errors are on  `MainWindow ^f;`:

```
1>c:\users\user\desktop\testlist\client\MyForm.h(19): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '^'
1>c:\users\user\desktop\testlist\client\MyForm.h(19): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>  MainWindow.cpp
```

How can i fix this problem?

______________________________Update for ArnonZilca

Myform - its a ref class, so i use ref struct and instead of `mreoer myvar;` i write `mreoer ^myvar;`

Errors in `mreoer ^myvar;` :

```
1>c:\users\user\desktop\testlist\client\MyForm.h(20): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '^'
1>c:\users\user\desktop\testlist\client\MyForm.h(20): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```

1>c:\users\user\desktop\client\client\MyForm.h(155): error C2227: left of '->Print' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
    1>  MainWindow.cpp

_________________________________UPDATE

So in Myform.h i write this:

```
 #pragma once

    namespace Client {
        ref class MainWindow;
        using namespace System;
        using namespace System::ComponentModel;
        using namespace System::Collections;
        using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
        using namespace System::Data;
        using namespace System::Drawing;

        public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
        {
        private:
            MainWindow ^f;  //this is my problem
        public:
            MyForm(void)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    ......
    ......
    ......
    }
```

and if i use this variable (^f) in MyForm.h i have this errors on line where i using it:

```
\users\user\desktop\client\client\MyForm.h(155): error C2027: use of undefined type 'Client::MainWindow'
1>          c:\users\user\desktop\client\client\MyForm.h(8) : see declaration of 'Client::MainWindow'
```

MainWindow have public method `void Print () { cout << "HEY" << endl; }`

In MyForm.h i do this: `f->Print();`

Comment: `#include "MainWindow.h"`? Assuming `MainWindow` is defined there...

Comment: first of all just to make sure, you put the `#include...` right after the `#pragma once`. Other than that, could you paste "MainWindow.h" (at least until the `MainWindow` class definition)?

Comment: I'm shooting blanks here... could it be that you're somehow missing a `;` after the definition of any of your classes ([explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092520/missing-before-template))?

Comment: @ArnonZilca no, bcz if i delete this line `MainWindow ^f;` works fine

Comment: let's try something. what if you add `struct mreoer {};` before the namespace definition in "MainWindow.h", make sure you still `#include "MainWindow.h"` in "MyForm.h", and instead of `MainWindow ^f;` write `mreoer myvar;`

Comment: This is really weird. I'm pretty sure it's something related to the configuration of your project, since code-wise you're doing everything right. Are those h & cpp files in different projects though in the same solution?

Comment: @ArnonZilca no, both are in one project..

Comment: @ArnonZilca You say about project config, which option may contribute to this error ?

Comment: I'm not sure since it's a long time since I used visual studio. I just thought that if they'd be on different projects you might need to reference the project (depend one on another). I think I don't have anymore ideas. sry. :\

Comment: @ArnonZilca i have the answer, see it :) Thx for helping!

Comment: sweet. :) I'm not sure forward declaring was mandatory in this scenario, but as long as it fixed your problem...

Comment: @ArnonZilca the problem is here again.. Can you read new update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tends to be a bit rough on programmers that are used to more recent languages.  But this is normal kind of problem to have, C++/CLI inherits the compilation model of the C++ language.  It is a single-pass compiler, all definitions must be known before you can use them.  A model that dates from the previous century, back when 64KB of RAM fit in shoebox and cost an arm and three legs.

Technically it isn't quite that bad, C++ is more like a 1.5 pass compiler.  You *can* refer ahead to class members inside inline function definitions.  Which doesn't exactly help to diagnose this kind of problem :)

But you must do the C++ dance here, your MyForm.h file can contain a forward declaration, `ref class MainWindow;` gets that done.  But any code that dereferences members of `f` must only appear in MyForm.cpp file. That .cpp file can #include both MyForm.h and MainWindow.h so all type definitions are available.  And yes, that *does* mean that you may well have to move methods that were added by the designer from the .h file to the .cpp file.  Do not panic, it's normal.

Comment: Yeah! Now it works, thank you very much! It really adds a lot of dancing( but it better if this did not works))

Answer (score 1):

It seems you forgot to include the header where Client::MainWindow is defined

Comment: the header of MyForm? Yes there no inlucde header, but if i add it, errors are remain.

Comment: Ok so it seems MainWindow is the parent of MyForm. So you can use a forward declaration of Client::MainWindow in MyForm.h (and in MyForm.cpp you add #include "MainWindow.h".

Comment: Errors like in the second example of errors in my question

Comment: What if you put `namespace Client { class MainWindow; }` right before the declaration of MyForm.h? (without #include "MainWindow.h" in MyForm.h)

Comment: `1>c:\users\user\desktop\testlist\client\MainWindow.h(18): error C3816: 'class Client::MainWindow' was previously declared or defined with a different managed modifier
1>          c:\users\user\desktop\testlist\client\MyForm.h(4) : see declaration of 'Client::MainWindow'
1>  MainWindow.cpp`

Comment: I forgot a ref in the forward declaration: `namespace Client { ref class MainWindow; }` should do the job

Comment: No, i have another problem.. see update please, maybe you can help me!